# Nexus 4 screen got hung until battery drained and on restart stuck on flying dots

Tags: nexus-4, boot, boot-loop, bootloader-lock, 5.1-lollipop

I have nexus 4 with lollypop installed on it. Yesterday while operating its screen just went to hung state and stopped responding. I could not even power off the phone. Therefore, I let the phone to drain out battery and switch off itself. Then I charged it started using power button. But it is stuck on 5 flying dots, more than an hour. The power key is not responding now. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but try booting into stock recovery and clearing cache and dalvik cache. Maybe there is something in there preventing it from booting all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, when battery is high, restarting the phone goes into a boot loop.

I wait for the phone to drain out, and then connect it to power source and switch it on at once. The phone now boots fine. I have no idea why it does that though.

Comment: If you're unsure what happened, it is not really useful as an answer.